# Using query with group_concat to loop values but show lowest price

Tags: php, mysql

I am using the query below to get all results and then then group them. It all works well. I now have multiple rows of identical data but with a different price.

How can I do the same query but get just the row with the cheapest price when all other data is identical. I have spent ages but no joy at all. Please help.

```
$results = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("    

SELECT *,   
group_concat(date,':',SUBSTRING_INDEX(flights,'|',2),':',price,':',board,':',$tablename.id separator ',') as itemx

FROM $tablename
WHERE post_type = 'product' 
GROUP BY brochure
LIMIT 20
"));
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  `SELECT *` with `GROUP BY` is a broken query that will fail in most databases and the more recent versions of MySQL (with the default options).

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, you want something like this:

```
SELECT t.*,   
FROM $tablename t
WHERE t.post_type = 'product' AND
      t.price = (SELECT MIN(t2.price)
                 FROM $tablename t2
                 WHERE t2.post_type = 'product' AND
                       t2.brochure = t.brochure
                );
```

This is at least a correctly constructed query that gets the minimum price for each brochure.

Comment: tks will give it a shot